# How to do Client side pagination for filtered data

Tags: yui-datatable

YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("genes", "change", function(e) {
        var value = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e).value;
             if(YAHOO.lang.isValue(value)) {
            myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest(null, {
                success:function(request, response, payload) {
                    this.initializeTable();

```
                var rs = response.results;
                var filtered = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
                      //alert(rs[i].gene);
                    if(rs[i].gene == value) {
                        filtered[filtered.length] = rs[i];
                    }
                }
                this.getRecordSet().setRecords(filtered, 0);
                this.render();
            },
            scope:myDataTable,
            argument:null
        });
    }
});
```

This is my code to filter the data. i am getting the data perfectly when i change the option for selection.
but the pagination is not working it is showing as '0' even the records are displayed.

can any one plz suggest me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
dobMenuButton.subscribe("selectedMenuItemChange",function(e) {
  var value =e.newValue.value;
  if(YAHOO.lang.isValue(value)) {
    myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest(null, {
        success:function(request, response, payload) {
            this.initializeTable();
            var rs = response.results;
            var filtered = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
                if(((rs[i].dateOfBirth).format("MM/dd/yyyy")) == value) {
                    filtered[filtered.length] = rs[i];
                }
            }
            this.getRecordSet().reset();                                                 
            MCMPagination.paginatorvar.setTotalRecords(filtered.length,true);
            this.getRecordSet().setRecords(filtered, 0);
            this.render();
    },
    scope:myDataTable, 
        argument:myDataTable.getState()
    });
   }
 });
```